# How to get Visual c++ to open d3dx.h

Tags: directx, visual-c++-2010, d3dx

Recently I have picked up a book on Game Programming using Visual C++. It uses the the DirectX library, and says that I only need to write #include  and #pragma comment(lib, "d3dx9.lib") into the code. However the program reports to be unable to find d3dx.h. How can I fix this.

I've tried adding the file in the Project Properties-Configuration properties-Linker-Input-Additional Dependencies yet it still cannot find the file. I am using Visual Studio 2010 if that changes anything.

I reports to be fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'd3dx.h': No such file or directory.

Comment: That's part of Direct3D extension library. You should install the DirectX SDK (Deprecated)

Answer (score 1):

You should read [this blog post](https://aka.ms/dxsdk) and [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009-).

**TL;DR:** Direct3D 9 is legacy, D3DX is deprecated, and the DirectX SDK (June 2010) is the end-of-life release. You can still use it, but you'd be better off learning DirectX 11 at this point.

Otherwise, install the legacy DirectX SDK (June 2010) from [Microsoft Downloads](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6812). Note that with VS 2010 you have to manually update the VC++ Directories to reference the DirectX SDK.

x86:

```
<ExecutablePath>$(DXSDK_DIR)Utilities\bin\x86;$(ExecutablePath)</ExecutablePath>
<IncludePath>$(DXSDK_DIR)Include;$(IncludePath)</IncludePath>
<LibraryPath>$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x86;$(LibraryPath)</LibraryPath>
```

x64:

```
<ExecutablePath>$(DXSDK_DIR)Utilities\bin\x64;$(DXSDK_DIR)Utilities\bin\x86;$(ExecutablePath)</ExecutablePath>
<IncludePath>$(DXSDK_DIR)Include;$(IncludePath)</IncludePath>
<LibraryPath>$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x64;$(LibraryPath)</LibraryPath>
```

With VS 2012 or later, you have to reverse those path orders (i.e. put the DXSDK_DIR paths after the existing ones) as documented at the bottom of [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009-).

> You should also be aware of this [known issue](https://walbourn.github.io/known-issue-directx-sdk-june-2010-setup-and-the-s1023-error/) that can cause problems installing the legacy DirectX SDK.